# Microsoft flow reading list user field value

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, powerapp

My scenario,i have a SharePoint list that upon creation of a new item should send a mail to someone.(that someone is read from the TO field(user field) in the list).Can you suggest me if is possible to use Microsoft flow directly and how. OR we need SharePoint designer for it

Answer (score 1):

You don't need sharepoint designer for flow.
login to https://flow.microsoft.com with your O365 account.

You will need 2 Actions to fulfill your requirements (refer screenshot below)

1. When item is created where you select the Site Collection in which list is present and then select the list for which the flow needs to be created.
2. Second action is Send an Email, quite self explanatory. you can refer screenshot below. when you click in **To** field, you will se dynamic content on right side which are nothing but the column names from the list selected in step 1, and create the Flow.

[image]

Comment: i dont see the To field in the dynamic content list,i see the other columns and To email,To Department,To Picture--can you explain please

Comment: just select your user column in To field of Send email action

Comment: If i add an attachement in the sharepoint list,how will that be send in that email then? can you enlighten me please

Comment: Click on show advance option in send email action and browse the attachment column

Comment: which option should i choose for Attachement Name/content.